# Convert int bits to float verbatim and print them

Tags: c++

I'm trying to just copy the contents of a 32-bit unsigned int to be used as float. Not casting it, just re-interpreting the integer bits to be used as float. I'm aware memcpy is the most-suggested option for this. However, when I do memcpy from uint_32 to float, and print out the individual bits, I see they are quite different.

Here is my code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void print_bits(unsigned n) {
  unsigned i;
  for(i=1u<<31;i > 0; i/=2)
    (n & i) ? printf("1"): printf("0");
}

union {
    uint32_t u_int;
    float u_float;
} my_union;

int main()
{
    uint32_t my_int =  0xc6f05705;
    float my_float;
    //Method 1 using memcpy
    memcpy(&my_float, &my_int, sizeof(my_float));
    //Print using function
    print_bits(my_int);
    printf("\n");
    print_bits(my_float);
    //Print using printf
    printf("\n%0x\n",my_int);
    printf("%0x\n",my_float);
    //Method 2 using unions
    my_union.u_int = 0xc6f05705;
    printf("union int = %0x\n",my_union.u_int);
    printf("union float = %0x\n",my_union.u_float);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
11000110111100000101011100000101
11111111111111111000011111010101
c6f05705
400865
union int = c6f05705
union float = 40087b
```

Can someone explain what's happening? I expected the bits to match. Didn't work with a union either.

Comment: One problem (there maybe others) is that, in your `print_bits(my_float);` call, the compiler will know that the function expects an `unsigned int` and will, thus, first convert your `float` variable to its (truncated) `unsigned int` representation **before** putting its value on the argument stack.

Comment: When you call `print_bits(my_float)` it performs a numeric conversion of the float to integer. So `1.0` is converted to the integer `1`, not an integer containing the representation of the float.

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast<unsigned>(my_float)` to get the conversion you want.

Comment: @Barmar Actually no, you can’t. You *could* cast the pointers, but that’s UB. `memcpy` is really the way to go here.

Comment: Also, the `400865` vs `40086b` issue (not reproducible on my Window/clang-cl system) looks like an endianness-related issue. The "end" nibbles are 0101 and 1101, so the "sign bit" could be interfering. What platform/compiler are you using?

Comment: Checkout the new C++20 function `bit_cast<>`. Perfect for this. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast

Comment: @Barmar You mean `reinterpret_cast<unsigned&>(my_float)`, although that is UB due to strict aliasing violation

Comment: @M.M Everything about this is either implement-defined or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the function print_bits to

```
inline
int is_big_endian(void)
{
    const union
    {
        uint32_t i;
        char c[sizeof(uint32_t)];
    } e = { 0x01000000 };

    return e.c[0];
}

void print_bits( const void *src, unsigned int size )
{
    //Check for the order of bytes in memory of the compiler:
    int t, c;
    if (is_big_endian())
    {
        t = 0;
        c = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        t = size - 1;
        c = -1;
    }
    for (; t >= 0 && t <= size - 1; t += c)
    {   //print the bits of each byte from the MSB to the LSB
        unsigned char i;
        unsigned char n = ((unsigned char*)src)[t];
        for(i = 1 << (CHAR_BIT - 1); i > 0; i /= 2)
        {
            printf("%d", (n & i) != 0);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int a = 7;
print_bits(&a, sizeof(a));
```

that way there won't be any type conversion when you call print_bits and it would work for any struct size.

EDIT: I replaced 7 with CHAR_BIT - 1 because the size of byte can be different than 8 bits.

EDIT 2: I added support for both little endian and big endian compilers.

Also as @M.M suggested in the comments if you want to you can use template to make the function call be: `print_bits(a)` instead of `print_bits(&a, sizeof(a))`

Comment: Surely it would be better to use a template, then the caller can just do `print_bits(a)`

Comment: @M.M I guess you can, since I saw that O.P. used printf I wrote it in c-style instead of c++. Also I personally don't think it matters that much, and this way gives you more freedom to pass any pointer (including void*) and choose any size.